# Energy Density of a Boson Star in non-relativistic Newtonian approximation

Tags: general-relativity, field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, approximations

I'm reading a paper called [Gravitational Atoms: Gravitational Radiation from excited boson stars](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.40.2524) ([RG](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/13277564_Gravitational_atoms_Gravitational_radiation_from_excited_boson_stars)) and in the paper after applying the weak field approximation to the Einstein Field equations given by:
$$
\Box h_{\mu\nu}=-16 \pi G S_{\mu\nu}
$$

they get the Poisson's equation given by:
\begin{equation}
\nabla^2 V = 8 \pi G m^2 |\phi|^2
\end{equation}
and then they proceed to say that the energy density is given by:
$$
\rho(x)= 2 m^2 |\phi(x)|^2
$$
They have used $S_{\mu\nu}=T_{\mu\nu}-\frac{1}{2} \eta_{\mu\nu}T $ and $$T_{\mu \nu}=\partial_\mu \Phi^* \partial_\nu \Phi+\partial_\nu \Phi^* \partial_\mu \Phi-\eta_{\mu \nu}\left(\eta^{\alpha \beta} \partial_\alpha \Phi^* \partial_\beta \Phi-m^2 \Phi^* \Phi\right) $$ and the metric is given by $$\eta_{\mu\nu}=diag(1,-1,-r^2,-r^2 \sin^2\theta)$$
When I substitute $\mu=0, \nu=0$ in order to calculate $S_{00}$, I get:
$$
S_{00}= \frac{1}{2} m^2 |\phi|^2
$$
in my calculations, I assign $\alpha=\beta=0$. Am I doing something wrong? Also am I wrong in assuming that $S_{00}$ is supposed to be the energy density?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the tensor that you call $S_{\mu \nu}$ appears to be the Ricci tensor (**so $S_{00}$ cannot be energy density**). For example, if I start from the [Einstein equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations) (with $8\pi G/c^4 = 1$) then I have
$$R_{\mu \nu}-\frac{1}{2} g_{\mu \nu} R=T_{\mu \nu}.$$
Now if I contract $T_{\mu \nu}$ with the inverse metric then
\begin{aligned} g^{\mu \nu} T_{\mu \nu} & =g^{\mu \nu} R_{\mu \nu} -\frac{1}{2} g^{\mu \nu} g_{\mu \nu} R \\ T & =R-2 R \\ T & =-R\end{aligned}

which then on substitution in the Einstein equations, gives me
$$ R_{\mu \nu}=T_{\mu \nu}-\frac{1}{2} g_{\mu \nu} T $$

**This is the same as your equation** but with $S_{\mu \nu}$ replaced with $R_{\mu \nu}$.
Since the tensor $T_{\mu \nu}$ is the energy-momentum tensor therefore, $T_{00}$ should be the energy density.

Note: I have used $g_{\mu \nu}$ in place of $\eta_{\mu \nu}$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. So, what I am able to understand is that my calculation for $S_{00}$ is wrong. It should come out to $m^2 \phi^2$ rather than what I am getting which is wrong by a factor of half.

Comment: I did not check the $S_{00}$ calculation, but I pointed out that $S_{00}$ is not the energy density term you are looking for. The energy density can be calculated by setting your term $\nabla^2 V = 8 \pi G m^2 |\phi|^2 = 4\pi G\rho$ (i.e.,  the Poisson's equation). This will give you $\rho = 2m^2 |\phi|^2$.